# jenkins - overriding environment variables on agent

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to be able to override default values per build, via "Run with parameters".

Currently, to enable someone to override environment variables on the agent I have this in my Jenkinsfile...

```
pipeline {
  parameters {    
    string(name: 'build_tsc', defaultValue: '', description: 'Override the path to the tsc executable')
  }
  stages {
    stage('Compiling') {
      steps {
        script {
          if (params.build_tsc) {
            echo "Compiling with tsc override: ${params.build_tsc}"
            bat "${params.build_tsc}"
          }
          else if (!env.JENKINS_TSC) {
            error("tsc not set on agent")
          }
          else {
            echo "Compiling with agent tsc: ${env.JENKINS_TSC}"
            bat "${env.JENKINS_TSC}"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: It would be easier and more robust to do a param with Map type and merge that into the env object, but otherwise yes: basically this.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the values in the JENKINS UI Node configuration page:
`${JENKINS_URL}/computer/{{NODE}}/configure`:

We do this where specific nodes have different configurations and have a groovy job that updates them based on the labels we have assigned (eg: WL1035 vs WL1036) when we add nodes or change the configuration.

[image: Node Properties Config]

You can also install the [Slave Setups plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/slave-setup/) to perform Node Configuration at launch time:

[image: Node Setup Cnonfig]

The above assumes you wish to override a global ENV or tool configuration for all jobs on the node.

Comment: Thanks but I should have said, I want to optionally override in the "Run with parameters" section. Idea is to be able to specify overrides for an individual build.